# Should I make my S3 bucket public for static site hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that is used to host a static site that is accessed through cloudfront.
I wish to use the s3 `<RoutingRules>` to redirect any 404 to the root of the request hostname. To do this I need to set the cloudfront origin to use the s3 "website endpoint".

However, it appears that to allow Cloudfront to access the s3 bucket via the "website endpoint" and not the "s3 REST API endpoint", I need to explicitly make the bucket public, namely, with a policy rule like:

```
{
            "Sid": "AllowPublicGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev.ts3.online-test/*"
},
{
            "Sid": "AllowPublicListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev.ts3.online-test"
}
```

That's all well and good. It works. However AWS gives me a nice big shiny warning saying:

> This bucket has public access. You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket.

So I have two questions I suppose:

1. Surely this warning should be caveated, and is just laziness on AWS' part? Everything in the bucket is static files that can be freely requested. There is no protected or secret content in the bucket. I don't see why giving public read is a security hole at all...
2. For peace of mind, is there any way to specify a principalId in the bucket policy that will only grant this to cloudfront? (I know if I use the REST endpoint I can set it to the OAI, but I can't use the rest endpoint)

Comment: As long as you don't mess up and put anything other than website files in that bucket it should be OK.   Everything in that bucket is visible to everyone.  They can see and download every file.  Do not put medical records, your tax returns, or 100 million user names and passwords in it  :)  .  The warning is so strong because many companies and government agencies have done all of the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing about the warning.

The list buckets view shows whether your bucket is publicly accessible. Amazon S3 labels the permissions for a bucket as follows:

**Public –**

- Everyone has access to one or more of the following: List objects, Write objects, Read and write permissions.

**Objects can be public –:**:

- The bucket is not public, but anyone with the appropriate permissions can grant public access to objects.

**Buckets and objects not public –:** 
- The bucket and objects do not have any public access.

**Only authorized users of this account –:**

- Access is isolated to IAM users and roles in this account and AWS service principals because there is a policy that grants public access.

So the warning due to first one. Recomended policy by AWS for s3 static website is below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Add a bucket policy to the website bucket that grants everyone access
>   to the objects in the bucket. When you configure a bucket as a
>   website, you must make the objects that you want to serve publicly
>   readable. To do so, you write a bucket policy that grants everyone
>   s3:GetObject permission. The following example bucket policy grants
>   everyone access to the objects in the example-bucket bucket.

BTW public access should be only **GET**, not anything else, Its totally fine to allow **GET** request for your static website on S3.

[image]
[static-website-hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html)

Comment: Are you saying that because the bucket policy statement limits actions to `s3:GetObject`, the warning against not blocking public access is moot?